# how can twisted Resource object render_Post return certain value after some defer

Tags: python, twisted

I should write some code like these:

```
class SomePage(Resource):
    def render_GET(self, request):
        d = DoSomeQuery()
        # if d run success
        # return "success"
        # if d fails
        # return "fail"
```

I mean the render_GET function return value depends on the defer result.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
d.addCallbacks(lambda _: "success",
               lambda _: "fail")
d.addCallback(request.write)
d.addBoth(lambda _: request.finish())
return server.NOT_DONE_YET
```